# How to force the twitter button to count only once per user?

Tags: twitter

If the user clicks on the tweet button of my web-app and tweets then a 1 is addet to the counter, but when he tweets again then the counter adds a 1 once more.

Is it possible to restrict the counter to count only once per user?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not change their api :)

I don't think it is happening like this and if it is happening like this it's ... then this is your first bug you found in twitter api :)))

Comment: no, there isn't if you haven't find it on twitter's api page :) maybe they will fix this.. because their script is being loaded every time on your page